# Whole number roots of a polynomial equation with a prime constant term

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

We have quadratic equation $x^2-4x-21-q=0$ and we know that $q$ is a prime number. The question is to find every value of $q$ where the equation has whole solutions. I found one $q=11$ but I don't understand how to prove that no other prime will satisfy this equation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might help to look at the discriminant (which has to be a perfect square, if the solutions are integers. The discriminant is $4q+100=4(q+25)$ , hence $q+25=k^2$ for some positive integer $k$. Take it from here.

Comment: I did that and found 11. The key says it's 11. I don't know how to prove no other number is the solution.

Comment: Second hint : Factor $k^2-25$ and consider that one factor must be $1$

Comment: $(k+5)(k-5)$ is the only way I am able to factor it, and I don't understand how to go from there.

Comment: Well, this is $q$ and therefore prime. One of the factors therefore must be $1$, which is it ? (Note that it is impossible that both factors are negative since $k+5$ is not negative, so both factors must be positive)

Comment: Aah I got it now. Thank you for help and giving hints instead of a direct answer. Have a good day sir!

Comment: Thank you, I'll do my very best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a hint from Mr. Peter. Taking the $D$<sub>1</sub>$=(\frac{b}{2})^2-ac=q+25$, for the solutions to be whole, $D$<sub>1</sub> must be a perfect square, so take some $k^2=q+25$. $$q=k^2-25$$ $$q=(k+5)(k-5)$$ For $q$ to be prime $k-5$ needs to be equal to $1$ since it is one of the two factors of a prime number. $$k-5=1$$ $$k=6$$ plug in $q=6^2-25=11$.
Check that value of $11$ for $q$ yields whole roots, which it does.